# Representation of Mo-roman numerals

Tags: no-computers, formation-of-numbers

<sub>This continues the spirit of [Mo-roman numerals](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/51189/19989) started by [humn](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18129/humn)</sub>

1. **What is/are the natural number(s) that has/have the most different representations in mo-Roman numerals and what is the number of representations in mo-Roman numerals where all the roman numerals are used once and only once?**
2. **What is/are the natural number(s) that has/have the fewest (at least 1) representations in mo-Roman numerals where all the roman numerals are used once and only once?**

An answer not containing an explanation is not a valid answer.
("Because the code I wrote said so" is not a valid answer. So no computers).

Explanations:

*What is a mo-Roman numeral?*
It's a number formed from Roman numerals but with more permissive rules.
Any roman numeral that has a larger numeral on his right side is subtracted, otherwise is added.
Example:
90 can be written in Roman numerals as `XC`. 
In Mo-roman numerals it can be written also as
$XCVVIXI = -10 + 100 - 5 - 5 - 1 + 10 + 1$

*What are the roman numerals and their values?*

$I = 1$
$V = 5$
$X = 10$
$L = 50$
$C = 100$
$D = 500$
$M = 1000$

*Note:* This is not meant to be a difficult puzzle. It is here to lure in more people to the mo-roman numerals questions.

Comment: If this keeps going, maybe we'll need *mo*-tags ;)

Comment: That was my secret agenda.

Comment: <sarcasm>I love how everyone is kind enough to explain a downvote</sarcasm>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Minimum:

> MDCLXVI (1666) is obvious. Then you have DMCLXVI as well where any other order of making 666 doesn't work - you need subtraction 1000-500 and this means D needs to be before M and is uniquely positioned. Any additional subtractions, say 466 or 1466 (where you subtract C) can be seen that C can come before M or before D, so you have 2 options. It continues the same way with other numbers (say I can come before any other number).

So, maximum is similar:

> IVXLCDM gives 1000-666 = 334. This number can be written by arbitrary order of letters before M, which have 6! positions. The other number of this property has the form of IVXLCMD. D is the last number and M (as well as other numbers) come at any spot before it. This number is 1334 (M+D - rest).

Comment: Close. Very close. There is one more number that qualifies for maximum. Same number of representations as the one you provided.

Comment: @Marius yeah you are right. I had the correct idea at minimum but managed to forget the same reasoning with maximum. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

## Partial Answer for part 1

The natural number that has *the most* representations is:

> Any number 
>  consider the number 4 as an example.
>  This can be represented as **IV** or **IIVI** or **IIIVII** or **IIIIVIII** or...
>  the number of representations of the number 4 is countably infinite and therefore, unless a number has an uncountably infinite number of representations, it has *the most* representations, just like every other number

Edit: This does not answer the second part of question 1, which asks about representations using only one of each digit.

Comment: I think you missed this part in the question: "where all the roman numerals are used once and only once"

Comment: In regards, to your edit. Your answer does not even answer the first part of the question. You missed a very important line. See my comment above.